# Other language $_POST are empty

Tags: php, codeigniter

I used to $_POST data to send data . when i send english data i can fetch
the data like 
echo "";print_r($_POST);
it return

Array
(
    [cate_id] => 1
    [super_category_name] => test
)

but when i used other fonts like in Hindi. and echo "";print_r($_POST);
it return :
Array
(
    [cat_id] => 1
    [super_category_name] => 
)

There is any solution to $_POST data in other language. that problem on my server not on my local system

pl z help me

Comment: Character encoding problem. Make sure your server character encoding is set to UTF-8.

Comment: accept-charset="UTF-8" 
Write this in form tag

Answer (score 0):

The accept-charset attribute specifies the character encodings that are to be used for the form submission.

If you set the encoding of the page to UTF-8 in a  and/or HTTP header, it will be interpreted as UTF-8, unless the user deliberately goes to the View->Encoding menu and selects a different encoding, overriding the one you specified.

In that case, accept-encoding would have the effect of setting the submission encoding back to UTF-8 in the face of the user messing about with the page encoding. However, this still won't work in IE, due the previous problems discussed with accept-encoding in that browser.

So it's IMO doubtful whether it's worth including accept-charset to fix the case where a non-IE user has deliberately sabotaged the page encoding (possibly messing up more on your page than just the form). Personally, I don't bother.